# Defining a locale for twig template translations when using `translation:update`

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I'm having a bit of trouble with Symfony twig translations, and I hope someone here can clarify.
Say I have a file /templates/general/hello_world.twig , with the contents:

```
{% trans with {
  '%name%': name,
  } %}
  "Hello %name%"
{% endtrans %}
```

When I call `bin/console translation:update --output-format=yaml fr --force` , the output file `translations/messages+intl-icu.fr.yaml` now contains the contents:

`'"Hello %name%"': '__"Hello %name%"'`

This is only the case with Twig files - I have other files in translations  where they are locale-suffixed, and those are properly translated into french.  I'm not clear what has to happen in order to get the `translation:update` command to recognize that the original content is in English?

I'm not asking how to choose a locale based on the user request.  I'm specifically wanting to generate missing translations for contents in my twig templates, and I'd love to have this command available to get me started.  The command works a treat for translations actually in the `/translations/` folder.

**Update 2**

```
// hello.twig
{% trans with {
    '%name%': name,
    } %}hello_world{% endtrans %}

//messages.en.yaml
hello_world: "Hello %name%"
```

Comment: the `__` prefix in `'__"Hello %name%"'` actually means "hey, this is not yet translated!". the locale (`fr`) you provide to the command tells, which locale's translation you want to update. so, it definitely provides "translations" for your texts, it doesn't actually translate stuff for you, though.

Comment: So, assuming I want to add a default english translation for this, how would I go about doing so?  I tried adding something like is indicated in "Update 2" (above), but no dice.

Comment: what do you mean with "default english translation", do you mean a default translation, which is to be pulled from english? afaik there's no such function. If the translation key (`hello_world` in your update) is already english (as was `"Hello %name%"`), you could run the translation:update command with an explicitly empty prefix, that might use that key. But I'm not quite sure, tbh.